# how to extract tables attributes like column name , datatype ,nullable for all the tables from the database from oracle pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

Is there any query that can be used to retrive the Tables and its column attributes like column name , datatype, nullable etc for all the tables inside the database

For Oracle Pl/SQL

Comment: Plsql and SQL Server? Odd combination. Perhaps they both have INFORMATION_SCHEMA support?

Answer (score 2):

The Oracle SQL you need would be the following (run as user 'SYS'):

```
select owner, table_name, column_name, data_type, nullable
from dba_tab_columns;
```

If you do a `desc dba_tab_columns` you will get a list of many more columns which may be of interest to you as part of your result set.
You can use a SQL tool (i.e. SQL*Plus) to run this query or you can use PL/SQL to call this query and put the results in PL/SQL variables then print them out via `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()`.

HTH